# Unity2D Sprite gone / not visible when flipped using Vector3.x

Tags: 2d, sprites, unity, materials

I have create game object with code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

private bool facingRight = true;
private float moveDirection = 0;
private Rigidbody2D theRigidbody2D = null;

void Start ()
{
    theRigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update ()
{
    moveDirection = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    theRigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection * 5, theRigidbody2D.velocity.y);

    if (moveDirection > 0 && !facingRight)
        Flip();
    else if (moveDirection < 0 && facingRight)
        Flip();

}

void Flip()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
    scale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = scale;
}
}
```

and using the material as shown below

[image]

In game while not facing left / while the game object is facing right :

[image]

But while the game object is not facing right / while the game object is facing left :

[image]

*The camera is follow the game object, so that's why i surround the camera with yellow rectangle

the question is, how can i fix this ? how can i fix the sprite to not gone even facing left state, or maybe any suggestion / method to do this ?

---

**EDIT [ HOW TO SOLVE THIS ]**

From the answer below, Fuzzy Logic told me to create 2-sided mesh / rectangle, or in this case maybe the sprite, but i have a problem there, then i try to create 2-sided shader from the orignal "Legacy Shaders/Transparent/Bumped Specular" and rename to "Legacy Shaders/Transparent/Bumped Specular 2 sided" with just adding a line of code:

```
Cull Off
```

after

```
SubShader {
    LOD 400
```

If you need full of shader code, you can download it [here](http://pastebin.com/CCXBKQHq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flip the texture, not the object. Sprite/Plane meshes are one-sided so if you flip the actual object, you are seeing the back of it, which is transparent.

Edit:
You could also make your mesh two-sided. But Unity doesn't provide a flat, 2-sided rectangle. You will have to make it, either in a modelling program or with code.

Answer (score -1):

One way I can try to assist in the resolution (given I am fairly new to programming) is to just use an animation of the character flipped the other way, in my case my character is just a square moving through space so its easier for me, if not then my appologies.